# how to store multiple checked values of checklistbox in database and then retrive in windows forms

Tags: c#-4.0

```
if (chklistmembership.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var checkedItem in this.chklistmembership.CheckedItems)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@membership",checkedItem.ToString() );
        //chklistmembership.SelectedItem.ToString());
    }
}
else
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@membership", DBNull.Value);
}
```

This is not working, it can store only 1 `checkeditem`.

Comment: SQL parameters can only take one value. Can you give an example of the SQL statement?

Comment: what sort of example.?? it's just an insert query

Comment: Given the code you have submitted, this could only add one `@membership` parameter. If you want to add multiple membership entries you would need to execute the insert query multiple times with different `@membership` parameters

Comment: so you mean i have to make multiple entries for only one person....???

Comment: It's very difficult to say given that I cannot see the query you are running nor the structure of the database table you are inserting into. If you can provide these I may be able to help.

Comment: inserted the user as many times the checkbox is checked. first i inserted by appending. but it cannot be fetch. well thanks a lot for your precious time sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i; i < $size; $i++)  
{
    $sql="INSERT INTO user_choice (user_id,prefrence_name) VALUES ('".$id."','".$checkbox1[$i]."')";

    $result = mysqli_query($dbh, $sql);
}
```

use this one